# how to enter day , month & year in dropdownlist from textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a 3 dropdownlist for Day, Month & year . I am trying to put date from textbox to dropdownlist by breaking date into day , month and year.
Heres the code:

```
DDLDay.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(txtspousedob.Text).Day.ToString();
DDLMonth.Text =Convert.ToDateTime(txtspousedob.Text).Month.ToString();
DDLYear.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(txtspousedob.Text).Year.ToString();
```

Date that I have is "01/01/2002" but I am getting is

> DDLDay gets "18"
>   DDLMonth gets "05"
>   DDLyear gets "2002"

So , what is the correct way to get the output

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `txtspousedob.Text` is `01/01/2002`? That's not possible to get `18/05` from that string. Can you please debug your code and tell us?

Comment: Try using the debugger to see the correct value of your textbox

Comment: I just did by putting in the breakpoint and that what indicated , which was even surprising for me

Answer (score 1):

You are probably left with the already selected text of drop down. First of all you need to ensure that the text you want to select. Then set the SelectedValue of the dropdown.

```
DDLDay.ClearSelection();
DDLDay.SelectedValue = DDLDay.Items.FindByText(txtspousedob.Text).Value;
```

Same applies to other `DropDownLists`

Comment: I tried this I wrote:`DDLDay.SelectedValue = DDLDay.Items.FindByText(txtspousedob.Text).Value;` but it gave error **Object refernce not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: First fill those drop downs with required data. Like days dropdown would have text and values from 1-31 for month of January for instance.

Comment: I have added items to the respective dropdown on page_load